# FTP: ftp_home_dir not existend

Tags: linux, centos, ftp

Okay so i installed the vstfpd (and ftp) i set the `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` File to the basevalues.

Now if i try to execute:

```
setsebool -P ftp_home_dir 1
```

It doesnt work. Error:

```
Boolean ftp_home_dir is not defined
```

Now if i execute:

```
semanage boolean -l | grep "ftp"
```

It prints out:

> ftpd_use_cifs                  (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to use cifs
>   ftpd_connect_db                (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to connect db
>   ftpd_use_fusefs                (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to use fusefs
>   ftpd_full_access               (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to full access
>   tftp_anon_write                (off  ,  off)  Allow tftp to anon write
>   tftp_home_dir                  (on   ,   on)  Allow tftp to home dir
>   httpd_can_connect_ftp          (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to can connect ftp
>   ftpd_use_passive_mode          (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to use passive mode
>   ftpd_use_nfs                   (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to use nfs
>   ftpd_connect_all_unreserved    (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to connect all unreserved
>   ftpd_anon_write                (off  ,  off)  Allow ftpd to anon write
>   httpd_enable_ftp_server        (off  ,  off)  Allow httpd to enable ftp server

As you see there is no `ftp_home_dir`. I don't want to use TFTP. So is there an possibility to add the `ftp_home_dir` to the booleans?

OS: CentOS 7 x86_64
it runs on a VM